# How to add two labels to a point in ListPlot, and how to control the precise positions of those labels?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, labeled

`ListPlot` has the option to label points using `Labeled` or `Callout`. At least those are the two ways to do it of which I am aware of. A simple example:

```
ListPlot[{Labeled[{1, 2}, "(1,2)"], Callout[{2, 1}, "(2,1)"]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}]
```

[image]

Now two questions:

1. How can I add two labels to one point? Each label should thereby be (roughly) opposite to its counter. Drawing the same plot twice as a workaround doesn't work. It would recognise the points as being too dense to display their labels.
2. Is there a way to have precise control over the label positions in terms of ocation angle and distance from the point? The option I know of is to specify `Callout[point,label,location]`, where `location` could be `Above,Below,Before,After,Left,Right`, or a pair thereof, such as `{Above,Right}`. But the latter seems bugged, and I would also appreciate a tighter control than just a grid with 45° angular resolution.

Here a graphical description of what I would like to do. I cannot add the code for this plot, because the curve in it is numerical.

[image]

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
points = RandomPoint[Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 3}], 10];
centroid = RegionCentroid@BoundingRegion[points, "FastDisk"];

labels1 = IntegerName /@ Range[Length@points];
labels2 = IntegerName[#, "French"] & /@ Range[Length@points];

gap = .2;

labeleddata = Table[MapThread[Callout[#, #2, # + i[[1]] gap Normalize[# - centroid], 
        Appearance -> "Leader"] &]@{points, i[[2]]},
     {i, {{-1, labels1}, {1, labels2}}}];

ListPlot[labeleddata, 
  LabelStyle -> 16,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
  AspectRatio -> 3/2, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> 60, ImageSize -> 600, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-3, 3}}, 
  Prolog -> Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can nest [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) and [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) individually or together. They can be individually positioned.

```
ListPlot[{Callout[Labeled[{1, 2}, "Label 1", Above], "Label 2", Below,
    Appearance -> None],
  Labeled[Callout[{2, 1}, "Label 1", Above, Appearance -> None], 
   "Label 2", Below],
  Labeled[Labeled[{.5, .5}, "Label 1", Above], "Label 2", Below],
  Callout[Callout[{1, 1}, "Label 1", Above, Appearance -> None], 
   "Label 2", Below, Appearance -> None]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}]
```

[image]

You can also use [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to overlap two plots using either `Labeled` or `Callout`

```
Show[
 ListPlot[{
   Labeled[{1, 2}, "Label 1", Above],
   Callout[{2, 1}, "Label 1", Above]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}],
 ListPlot[{
   Labeled[{1, 2}, "Label 2", Below],
   Callout[{2, 1}, "Label 2", Below]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}}]]
```

[image]

For more precise positioning you can use [`Text`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) in an [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2}, {2, 1}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2.5}, {0, 2.5}},
 Epilog -> {
   Text["Label 1", {1, 2}, {1.5, 1.25}],
   Text["Label 2", {1, 2}, {-1.5, -1.25}],
   Text["Label 1", {2, 1}, {1.5, -1.25}],
   Text["Label 2", {2, 1}, {-1.5, 1.25}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon Thank you so much! I suppose this would qualify as solution as well. However I ended up marking kglr's solution as such, since it is more directly what I was looking for.